# How to check data usage of mobile for specific sim slot in android?

Tags: android, slot, dual-sim

I am trying to find data usage by specific SIM slot. For this I am using TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() method but it gives total usage of both the SIM in dual SIM device.

Below is my code that return me total usage:

```
 long rxBytes = (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX)/ 1048576;
        RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
        long txBytes = (TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX)/ 1048576;
        TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));

        Log.d("totalWifiRe", (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes())/ 1048576+" MB");
        Log.d("totalWifiTx", (TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes())/ 1048576+" MB");
        Log.d("totalDataRe", (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()/ 1048576)+" MB");
        Log.d("totalDataTx", (TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()/ 1048576)+" MB");
        Log.d("SIM_STATUS", TrafficStats.getThreadStatsTag()+"");
        Log.d("DailyNetUsage", "");
        Log.d("CurrentTx", txBytes+" MB");
        Log.d("CurrentRx", rxBytes+" MB");
```

I want particular data usage of individual SIM. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Some Application are doing that like smartapp.